# How do i get sculpting mode back?

Tags: sculpting

First time using Blender. I've been sculpting for a while, but when I switched to the editing mode from the sculpting mode,  it doesn't show sculpting mode as an option anymore. How I get back to it? I mean, I don't have any tools to sculpt and the drop menu only shows Object mode and edit mode instead of various modes.

Answer (score 1):

just click on object mode and go up to sculpt mode
[image]